# What exactly is the nginx request_uri?

Tags: nginx, documentation

I'm trying to understand the `$request_uri` variable in nginx configuration. The documentation says

> full original request URI (with arguments)

To me that seems to be totally unambiguous - it should be the entire requested URI, including the host and protocol. But in actual usage, it seems to only include the path & query arguments. Is there any authoritative source that says exactly what nginx considers to be a request_uri? I can't find any further references in the documentation, and I tried to get it out of the source code, but there are no comments and it's hard to understand the overall structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *Request-URI* does not refer to the [RFC 3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986) URI, but is a term from [RFC 2616, 5.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-5.1.2) HTTP/1.1 *draft standard* from 1999.

The *Request-URI* in RFC 2616 could have been any of:

> `Request-URI    = "*" | absoluteURI | abs_path | authority`

Here, the `absoluteURI` is equivalent with the RFC 3986 URI, and mainly used in HTTP proxys. Søren Løvborg explains in an [answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61612354) why it is not necessary to have the full URI in this context:

> In normal HTTP requests, the URL scheme and host have already been handled by the time the request is sent (and the URL fragment does not exist at the HTTP protocol level at all), meaning the Request-URI is a [path-absolute-URL string](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#path-absolute-url-string), possibly followed by `?` and a [URL-query string](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#url-query-string).

*Request-URI* seems to be replaced with the (more unambiguous) term *Request Target* in [RFC 7230, 3.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.3) *proposed standard* from 2014, where a *Request Line*...

> begins with a method token, followed by a single space (`SP`), the `request-target`, another single space (`SP`), the protocol version, and ends with `CRLF`.
>
> `request-line   = method SP request-target SP HTTP-version CRLF`

The *Request Target* term is also used in the [RFC 9110, 7.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#section-7.1) of the *Internet Standard* (June 2022); *URI References* are defined in [RFC 9110, 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#section-4.1).

Comment: Thanks for the references! Is it safe to assume that "Request-URI" always refers to the path, args, etc. or is it genuinely ambiguous? As for the justification, that does make sense.